# How do I read strings from a file that already contain double quotes?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner, filereader

I have a list of names in a `.txt` file which are in the format:

> "Tim", "Dave", "Simon"

The input will always be single value names in quotes, comma separated and on a single line.

I want to read these into `String[] names`.

I have the following code, but the output puts each of them in double quotes, meaning it looks like:

""Tim"", ""Dave"", ""Simon""

I'm also not able to use any third party libs.

How do I get it so that each element in the String array only has one set of double quotes?

```
String[] names = {};

// arraylist to store strings
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

// load content of file based on specific delimiter
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("names.txt")).useDelimiter(",");
String str;

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    str = sc.next();
    listOfStrings.add(str);
}
```

Comment: You can do `add(str.replaceAll("\\"", ""));`

Comment: How are you outputting them? Reading them won’t *add* quotes, so that’s happening elsewhere—each element only has one set of quotes. Are you asking how to *remove* the quotes in the strings you read in?

Comment: Excellent, did the trick. Although I didn't need the escape char, so `add(str.replaceAll("\"", ""))` worked.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm debugging them so can see the ""Tim"" etc in the array elements

Comment: That looks like your data is in CSV format, since double-quotes are used around fields that contain commas (but no technical reason why that should not apply to all fields).  Upshot is, you can use a CSV library, like opencsv or Apache’s csvreader.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat That says *what* you’re doing, but now *how*. If you print the string as-is there’s no extra quotes—so you must be printing your own extra quotes. So you’re asking how to remove the quotes from the strings you’re reading in.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat I think you need to determine if this IS csv (coma-separated values) file, where values MAY contain commas (that are distinct from the field separators).  For example, what if one of the values did contain a comma - eg, your example was `"Tim", "Smith,Dave", "Simon"` (so the middle name is `Smith,Dave`?  A CSV library would handle that, whereas a simple `replaceAll` would split that line into 4 entries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry. Actually this is better

```
add(s.replace("\"", ""));
```

Comment: Obviously the input is CSV encoded and this won't actually work. Imagine the input has actual quotes in, for example.

Comment: If you look more carefully at the code it is *not* treated as CSV or it would not be being added to *one* collection. *Plus* the code is designed to read one line only

Comment: thanks, is there a way to directly insert these into a `String []` without doing `String[] names= listOfStrings.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: You'd get that if you split the entire line on a comma. See `String.split`

Comment: `String.split` still gives ""Tim""

Comment: `String.split` is nothing to do with removing quote characters. We've already covered that

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of names in a .txt file which are already in a String format:

They actually aren't; that is not 'string format'; there is in fact no such thing as 'string format'.

Given that the input file contains quotes and you know those quotes aren't literally part of the input, merely delimiting the input, we can reduce the reasonable guesses as to what format this actually is. Down to just two commonly used formats, in fact:

### Standard CSV format

"CSV" ("Character Separated Values") is an extremely common data interchange format. Unfortunately, there is no spec. But by far the most common 'take' on this format involves the following escaping rules:

- Newline separates record.
- Some specified character separates 2 items in a single record; usually a comma, a tab, or a semicolon - clearly comma in your input.
- So.. what to do if one of the items contains, literally, a comma or newline? The usual answer is to enclose the input in quotes in this case, and sometimes, a CSV output tool quote-delimits everything, even if it wasn't needed (Such as, presumably, your example). However, this then raises yet another question: What if the input contains quotes. Then, the answer is to double them up. So, the literal string: `Jane said: "Well, hello there!"` becomes, in `example.csv`:

```
"Jane said: ""Well, hello there!"""
```

There's even a standard for this: [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). It's a one-pager. Feel free to have a quick look at it.

### backslash-escape CSV

An alternative, that has become more popular given that about 90% of all programming languages have string constants that work like this, is to treat the backslash symbol as an escape symbol: A backslash is always followed by a character and the pair together tell you what's actually intended based on a lookup table. The common escapes are:

- `\n` -> That's a newline
- `\t` -> a tab
- `\"` -> a literal quote
- `\,` -> a literal comma

and a few more (`\r`, `\f`, `\b`, `\123`, `\u1234` are all somewhat common).

There's simply no way to know unless the source of this text file tells you which format it is, or by getting more complicated inputs that contain such strings. If you can control the actual literal text that is outputted, make a complicated string with newlines and commas and double quotes in the literal text, export it to this text file and see what it looks like.

### So how do I parse this?

It's very complicated - code that properly parses it all is many pages long. You're in luck, though! Plenty of libraries exist.

The usual way to go is to use [OpenCSV](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv) - that's a tutorial that takes you through how to use it.

### I just want one string with literally `Tim, Dave, Simon`

Well, that's just not what your input file says; clearly then your input file is in some unknown format, and you're going to have to explain how in the blazes you get from the notion that the text file contains `"Tim", "Dave", "Simon"` to desiring `Tim, Dave, Simon` in a single string variable. Perhaps the input is indeed in CSV and you simply want each item concatenated together, separated out by a comma. In which case, use OpenCSV to read it, and then write the very simple code required to concatenate the items. OpenCSV can give you a `List<String>` to represent a 'line' of input - to turn that into a single comma separated string, that's easy:

```
String[] csvLine = opencsv.readNext();
String output = String.join(", ", csvLine);
assert output.equals("Tim, Dave, Simon");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the input will always be names in quotes, comma separated and i would prefer a standard lib approach without using third party libs.  I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: CSV parsing is just hard, period. The java standard library does not contain CSV parsers. Conclusion: Third party deps are required here, or you need to accept that it's complicated (multiple days of programming, even for a fairly experienced programmer, with lots of funky inputs for testing). The fact that 'it is always in quotes' doesn't make it any simpler, the problem is when there are newlines, commas, or quotes in the input.